# How to write to shapefile in MapGuide

Tags: shapefile, open-source-gis, mapguide, php

Here the code I have written to a shapefile in MapGuide Open Source (in PHP running on IIS 7.5). The code is actually the modified class MarkupEditor (markupeditor.php) from the General Tracks (GT) example.

```
class MarkupEditor
{
    private $args = null;
    private $site = null;
    function __construct($args){
        $this->args = $args;
        $this->site = new MgSiteConnection();
        $this->site->Open(new MgUserInformation($args['SESSION']));
    }
    //
    // Rest of the original code in the class
    //
    function AddPointToShp($featureID){
        $geometryFactory = new MgGeometryFactory();
        $agfWriter = new MgAgfReaderWriter();
        $vertices = explode(",", $this->args['GEOMETRY']);
        $coord = $geometryFactory->CreateCoordinateXY((double) $vertices[0], (double) $vertices[1]);
        $point = $geometryFactory->CreatePoint($coord);
        $point = $point->Transform($this->GetTransform());
        $byteReader = $agfWriter->Write($point);
        $propertyValues = new MgPropertyCollection();
        $propertyValues->Add(new MgInt32Property("FeatId", $featureID));
        $propertyValues->Add(new MgStringProperty("TYPE", "Breader"));
        $propertyValues->Add(new MgStringProperty("DESC", "OCB'));
        $propertyValues->Add(new MgGeometryProperty("Geometry", $byteReader));
        $this->InsertMarkupFeatureToShp($propertyValues);
    }

    function InsertMarkupFeatureToShp($propertyValues){
        try{
            $featureService = $this->site->CreateService(MgServiceType::FeatureService);
            $featureSourceId = $this->args['MARKUPLAYER'];
            $commands = new MgFeatureCommandCollection();
            $commands->Add(new MgInsertFeatures($this->args['OPENMAKUP'], $propertyValues));
            $featureService->UpdateFeatures($featureSourceId, $commands, false);
        }
        catch (MgFeatureServiceException $ex){
            echo '<b>MgFeatureServiceException : </b>'.$ex->GetExceptionMessage();
        }
        catch (MgInvalidArgumentException $ex){
            echo '<b>MgInvalidArgumentException : </b>'.$ex->GetExceptionMessage();
        }
        catch (MgInvalidOperationException $ex){
            echo '<b>MgInvalidOperationException : </b>'.$ex->GetExceptionMessage();
        }
        catch (MgFdoException $ex){
            echo '<b>MgFdoException : </b>'.$ex->GetExceptionMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

The members of $args array passed in the constructor are:

```
Array
(
    [MARKUPLAYER] => Library://DataStore/Data/Electrical/Breaker.FeatureSource
    [SESSION] => 970bab06-4bd2-11e1-8000-000000000000_en_7F0000010AFC0AFB0AFA
    [MAPNAME] => DataStore
    [OPENMARKUP] => Default:breaker
    [TGT] => 1
    [POPUP] => 0
    [GEOMETRY] => 1.5041909054501184,0.39827301781943014
)
```

**`$featureID`** in function **`AddPointToShp()`** is a numeric value. The code always stops execution at this line in function **InsertMarkupFeatureToShp()**:

```
$featureService->UpdateFeatures($featureSourceId, $commands, false);
```

It does not even generate an exception so that I may be able to find out what is wrong.

Some posts on **osgeo.org** say that GT Example is used to write to SDF only. Where as, I am able to read any field from a desired shapefile using some other modified functions in the same file.

Any help please?

**UPDATE**

I have converted the target Coordinate System to the one as in existing shapefile. Now I get the **MgInvalidArgumentException**:

```
Invalid argument(s): [1] = " " The string cannot be empty.
```

Also I have tested **`$propertyValues`** [`$propertyValues->GetCount()`]. It returns the count as 4.

Comment: aww man, that's a lot of "->" haha. dont understand exactly what you're trying to do from your code, can you explain it in plain english? typically, i like to use gen2shp. it's dead simple to create the gen format then convert it to shp using that program. But i dont think that's what you're looking for?

Comment: :) I simply want to write new Point, Line or Polygon (whose co-ordinates are known), to an existing SHP file.

Comment: sorry I don't have any suggestions on your issue, but I'm currently having lots of trouble with the same setup (MapGuide OS 2.1, PHP, IIS 7.5). If you are feeling charitable I'd love to start a conversation about how you configured it

Comment: @tomfumb: Sorry! Was on long holidays. It's not about feeling charitable. I have went through the same you are facing. I am available for conversation and let's see, what we can do in your case.

Comment: @kush.impetus thanks very much for the offer but I had to give up on this approach due to time / budget issues. I think my problem was 64-bit IIS not talking properly to 32-bit ISAPI component in MapGuide. Eventually I just installed MapGuide with bundled Apache and set an IIS site to forward all requests to Apache. It's not ideal but it works and shows good performance. I also tried figuring this out in the MapGuide forum here: http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/MGOS-Windows-Server-2008R2-mapagent-fcgi-isapi-MapAgent-dll-50x-errors-td4466466.html

Comment: @tomfumb: I myself am running MapGuide on 64-bit Windows 7. Setting up was bit tricky, but it works fine now. I tried running Apache configuration of MapGuide, but could not do that. Can you tell me what points must be taken care-of while installing Apache configuration?

Comment: @kush.impetus in my experience the apache install is the easiest as you can have multiple apache installs on a machine. The bundled MG installer contains everything (apache, PHP 5.2.5 NTS) within the OSGeo/MapGuide directory and is completely self-contained. I installed the bundle with the defaults, then used IIS URL Rewrite in reverse-proxy mode to forward all traffic for a dedicated IIS site to localhost:8008 (MG apache). Then I configured a few aliases (including /mapguide) within apache's httpd.conf and everything was OK.

Comment: @tomfumb: I have managed to install MapGuide with Apache configuration. So far, I am able to run `http://localhost:8008/mapguide/mapadmin`. The looking at the interface, it is clear that MapGuide in IIS and Apache configuration share same users' list and data. But I cannot run a site hosted in mapguide on Apache configuration, e.g. using this: `http://localhost:8008/mapguide/phpviewersample`, where as I can run this: `http://localhost/mapguide/phpviewersample`. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: @kush.impetus you don't specify what exactly fails, but I would guess the PHP version is a good place to start. If you installed php via the Windows installer it will be on the path and might be executing the MapGuide PHP instead of letting the bundled PHP version execute it. Try dropping a phpinfo() in the phpviewersample directory and see what you get - e.g. does it use the php.ini configuration from the MapGuide install dir or somewhere else? If it uses the right php.ini try editing this to enable error logging to syslog then check your event viewer.

Comment: @kush.impetus also, just checking - when you test phpviewersample do you explicitly specify the .php file, or are you waiting for a default document? Double check by visiting phpviewersample/ajaxviewersample.php

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late on this one but perhaps you are required to pass a MgResourceIdentifier to UpdateFeatures ?

So

```
$featureService->UpdateFeatures($featureSourceId, $commands, false);
```

might require changing to

```
$featureResSourceId = new MgResourceIdentifier($featureResSourceId);
$featureService->UpdateFeatures($featureResSourceId, $commands, false);
```

Don't forget that this will change your library dataset it may be read only depending on the current logged on user.